# R Reshape data by combining common value of two variables

Tags: r, igraph, reshape

I want to reshape a data frame by combining two variables. 
For example:

Here is a new data:

```
    dat = data.frame(
    var1 = c("a", "a", "a", "Emily", "b", "Bob", "c"),
    var2 = c("Jhon", "Emily", "Julie", "Angela", "Bob", "Paul", "Paul"),
    stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Excepted output:

```
  #   var1   var2   var3   var4   var5 
  # 1    a   Jhon  Emily  Julie Angela
  # 2    b    Bob   Paul      c   <NA>
```

Comment: Should be possible using `igraph` package.

Comment: Your example data and the presented data don't fit together, the last row is different and in the text it should read that Bob and Paul have a relation, or?

Comment: @hannes101 Already updated. Thanks for your remind

Answer (score 2):

Using base R you can do:

```
relation=function(dat){

 .relation=function(x){
    k = unique(sort(c(dat[dat[, 1] %in% x, 2], x, dat[dat[, 2] %in% x, 1])))
    if(setequal(x,k)) toString(k) else .relation(k)}

  grp = sapply(unique(dat[,1]), .relation)
  read.table(text = unique(grp), fill=T, sep=",")
}

relation(dat)
  V1      V2     V3    V4     V5
1  a  Angela  Emily  Jhon  Julie
2  b     Bob      c  Paul
```

Comment: `dat = data.frame(var1 = c("a", "a", "a", "Emily", "b", "Bob", "c"),                   var2 = c("Jhon", "Emily", "Julie", "Angela", "Bob", "Paul", "Paul"), stringsAsFactors = F)` If the data is like this way, there is a problem. I have already updated my post

Comment: @velvetrock what problem is there?

Comment: @velvetrock Is `paul` supposed to be in `b` or in `c`??

Comment: Here is the output if I use your code:       
` # var1 var2.1 var2.2 var2.3 var2.4       # 1    a   Jhon  Emily  Julie Angela       # 5    b    Bob   Paul   Paul   <NA>`

Comment: Paul has a relation with b, c and Bob

Comment: @velvetrock so how do you determine values that should be in `var1` ?? ie why only `a` and `b`??

Comment: var1 could be Emily and Paul also, I don't care the order of each group, I just want to put those who has a relation into a row

Comment: @Onyambu, can you detail on algorithm on what is happening? It is a great solution. But, I am not clear on every step of that

Comment: @user5249203 it is a recursion, I bet we could improve it. I wrote it sometime back.

Comment: Yeah, Trying to wrap it in as a Rcpp function. Would you mind adding comments at each step ?

Comment: @user5249203 is that like `c++`? the normal `c++`?

Comment: Its normal c++,  you can integrate in  R. http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html

Comment: @I really don't remember what I was doing here. Let me look through it. I guess then I might try and teach myself C++ and write this in C++

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177813/discussion-between-user5249203-and-onyambu).

Answer (score 1):

```
dat = data.frame(var1 = c("a", "a", "a", "Emily", "b", "Bob"), 
                 var2 = c("Jhon", "Emily", "Julie", "Angela", "Bob", "Paul"))

library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(dat)
plot(g)
starts <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "in") == 0] 
finals <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "out") == 0]
res <- lapply(starts, function(x) unique(names(unlist(all_simple_paths(g, 
                                                            from = x, 
                                                            to = finals, 
                                                            mode = "out")))))
res

# matrix/data frame (?)
max_len <- max(sapply(res, length))
data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(res, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_len - length(x))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have produced a solution which first "cleans" the data structure and then reshapes it using `dcast`.

```
library(data.table)

dt.dat <- data.table(dat)

# Cleaning the dataset by adding the persons not assigned to a group by the connection over names
dt.dat.complete <- 
rbindlist(list(dt.dat[!(var1 %in% merge(dt.dat, dt.dat, by.x = "var2", by.y = "var1")[,var2]),]
          , 
merge(dt.dat, dt.dat, by.x = "var2", by.y = "var1")[, .(var1, var2.y)]
))

# Add sequence for the column names
dt.dat.complete[,seq := seq_len(.N), 
                    by=var1]

dcast.data.table(dt.dat.complete, var1  ~ paste0("col",seq) + seq,fun.aggregate = NULL, value.var = "var2")

     var1 col1_1 col2_2 col3_3 col4_4
1:    a   Jhon  Emily  Julie Angela
2:    b    Bob   Paul   <NA>   <NA>
```