# How can I modify these dplyr code for multiple linear regression by combination of all variables in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, linear-regression, tidyverse

lets say I have following data

```
ind1 <- rnorm(99)
ind2 <- rnorm(99)
ind3 <- rnorm(99)
ind4 <- rnorm(99)
ind5 <- rnorm(99)
dep <- rnorm(99, mean=ind1)
group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=33)
df <- data.frame(dep,group, ind1, ind2, ind3, ind4, ind5)
```

the following code is calculating multiple linear regression between dependend variable and 2 independent variables by group which is exactly what I want to do. But I want to regress dep variable against all combination pair of independent variables at once. So how can I combine other models in this code?

```
df %>% 
  nest(-group) %>% 
  mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(dep ~ ind1 + ind2, data = .)),
         results1 = map(fit, glance),
         results2 = map(fit, tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(results1) %>% 
  unnest(results2) %>% 
  select(group, term, estimate, r.squared, p.value, AIC) %>% 
  mutate(estimate = exp(estimate))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note more than `dplyr` is used in attempted code: `dplyr != tinyverse` but `dplyr %in% tinyverse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full tidy answer. Consider building all [possible combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51993770/1422451) of linear formulas with `rapply` after initial build with `lapply` and `combn` then pass into your tidy method:

```
indvar_list <- lapply(1:5, function(x) 
                 combn(paste0("ind", 1:5), x, , simplify = FALSE))

formulas_list <- rapply(indvar_list, function(x)
                   as.formula(paste("dep ~", paste(x, collapse="+"))))

run_model <- function(f) {    
    df %>% 
      nest(-group) %>% 
      mutate(fit = map(data, ~ lm(f, data = .)),
             results1 = map(fit, glance),
             results2 = map(fit, tidy)) %>% 
      unnest(results1) %>% 
      unnest(results2) %>% 
      select(group, term, estimate, r.squared, p.value, AIC) %>% 
      mutate(estimate = exp(estimate))
}

tibble_list <- lapply(formulas_list, run_model)
```

Comment: @ Parfait. Thank you! what if my independent variables have different names like height, weight, volume, mass etc (not all started with ind) to create indvar_list?

Comment: Then replace input argument of `combn` with a vector of variable names: `combn(c("type", "height", "weight", "volume", "mass"), x, simplify=FALSE)`. Be sure the `lapply` runs in sequence from 1 to total number of independent variables. Also, see edit with syntax corrections regarding `rapply`.

Comment: @ Parfait. Thank you very much!. It helped me a lot.

Comment: I am sorry. I run the code. But I am getting this for all combination "[[31]]
function (f) 
{
    df %>% nest(-group) %>% mutate(fit = map(data, ~lm(f, data = .)), 
        results1 = map(fit, glance), results2 = map(fit, tidy)) %>% 
        unnest(results1) %>% unnest(results2) %>% select(group, 
        term, estimate, r.squared, p.value, AIC) %>% mutate(estimate = exp(estimate)). 
}".

Comment: Hmmmm...carefully check implementation. You may have changed something from this solution as your method appears to return the function's definition and not function's evaluation. See output I get for the 31st item of *tibble_list*: https://pastebin.com/70HAqhas.