# Is there an R function to alter the name columns in this script?

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

Hello I am trying to generate a time series least square regression with multiple combinations with a set of variables incluiding their lags. I found this useful link:

[How can I modify these dplyr code for multiple linear regression by combination of all variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56093202/how-can-i-modify-these-dplyr-code-for-multiple-linear-regression-by-combination).

But when I try to replicate, I obtain this error:

[image: that appears in this image]

I try to use the vec_names() package, but it says that have to be a character vector or the rename package but it didn't recognize it.

Comment: The `dplyr` functions `rename_with` and `rename` allow to change the name of multiple columns, but in your case, the error gives the solution. The problem is that `glance`, and therefore `unnest(result1)` produce columns `statistic` and `p.value` relative to the model, while `tidy` and therefore `unnest(result2)` produce columns `statistic` and `p.value` relative to the estimates. The error gives the solution because it tells using the argument `names_repair`. For example, you can add `unnest(results2, names_repair = tidyr_legacy)`

Comment: @iago, please post your suggestion as a solution, so that it helps others looking for same/similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help @iago